# While Adding TabBarNavigation error in version 5.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is the code.Here i want to create BottomTabs and i used  react native version 5.x npm packages .if i remove the tabbar it will work.

```js
import { Ionicons, AntDesign } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
```

```
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Home"
  screenOptions={({route}) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
        let iconName;
        if (route.name === 'Home') {
          iconName = focused
            ? 'ios-information-circle'
            : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
        } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
          iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-box' : 'ios-list';
        }
        // You can return any component that you like here!
        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
      };
    },
  )}
  tabBarOptions={{
    activeTintColor: 'tomato',
    inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
  }}>
  <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={search} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

**Error included below**
[image: error]

Comment: The error is within the `tabBarIcon` option for your navigator. How are you importing Ionicons?

Comment: @MarekLisik Ionicons are imported using this => import {
  Ionicons,
  AntDesign,
} from 'react-native-vector-icons';

Comment: I’m voting to close this question. Don't add print-screens of error messages, add them as plain text to make them indexable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61193129/while-adding-tabbarnavigation-error-in-version-5-x#comment108267871_61193129), you are importing the icon components like so:

```js
import { AntDesign, Ionicons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
```

The way the vector-icons package exports those components is a little different. Change your import statement to the following:

```js
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,errors are gone but still icons are not showing.